# How to Set content security policy in vue 3 compotion api typescript

Tags: .net-core, webpack, vuejs3, content-security-policy, vue-cli

i need to set CSP in my vue 3 project.
I tried to set below line in index.html from public folder and in head section

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com; img-src 'self' data:; frame-src 'self';connect-src *;"/>
```

But when i run project it throws error because auto generated js and css files need to set by nonce or hash.. I don't know how to use nonce in vue3 app. (Note = i have api in dot net core 6 and this frontend and backend both will be hosted on windows server)